# How to make a JSON file new line delimited in NiFi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

So I'm working with a batch JSON file that could have over 2,000 variables within it, and I'm trying to make the JSON file into a new line delimited. For example, the JSON file I'm receiving is:

```json
[
  {
    "Test1": 1,
    "Test2": 2,
    "Test3": 3
  },
  {
    "Test4": 4,
    "Test5": 5
  },
  {
    "Test6": 6,
    "Test7": 7,
    "Test8": 8
  },
  {
    "Test9": 9,
    "Test10": 10
  }
]
```

My end goal is the following:

```json
{
  "Test1": 1,
  "Test2": 2,
  "Test3": 3
}
{
  "Test4": 4,
  "Test5": 5
}
{
  "Test6": 6,
  "Test7": 7,
  "Test8": 8
}
{
  "Test9": 9,
  "Test10": 10
}
```

As you can see for the final output there is no longer a square bracket or comma's that are separating other curly brackets. I figured out a way through a `ReplaceText` processor to get rid of the square brackets `[ ]` but I'm having trouble getting rid of the `,` between the curly brackets and making the file a new line delimited JSON file. I know there is a way to `SplitJSON` then do a `MergeContent` processor to make this work properly. I'm trying to see if there is another way of doing this without splitting the file up and merging it back together.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Splitjson + merge content seems to be a good solution. The only alternative - script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with `ReplaceText`, after getting rid of brackets, replace `},{` with `}shift+enter{`

[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!! Really appreciate it!!