# Nifi - edit json flow file content

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I am using Nifi 1.6.0. I am trying to copy an S3 file into redshift. The json file on S3  looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4
  }
]
```

However this gives an error (Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.)                      because of '[' and ']' in the file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348425).

I need to convert the json from above format to a format which looks like this:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 4
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to remove `'['` and `']'` and replace `'},\n'` with `'}\n'`.

The file has over 14 million rows (113 MB in size)

How can I achieve this using Nifi?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReplaceText`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623892/how-to-make-a-json-file-new-line-delimited-in-nifi). It is very similar to your problem. First replace brackets with empty string then replace commas by using `LiteralReplace` strategy